# Finding the intersection of two points and an arbitrary axis

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

Given two points I would like to find where the line joining them intersects an arbitrary axis.  For example, if I had one point $(5, 10)$ and another at $(50, 100)$ I can be sure that somewhere a line joining these two points will intersect a line running parallel to the $x$ axis with the $y$ value of $23$.  Is it possible to determine the $x$ value at this point of intersection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [equation of a straight line is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_a_line#Linear_equations_in_two_variables)

$$y=mx+b.\qquad (1)$$

If the line passes through $P_{1}(x_{1},y_{1})$, then

$$y_{1}=mx_{1}+b\qquad (2)$$

and

$$b=y_{1}-mx_{1}.\qquad (3)$$

If it passes through $P_{2}(x_{2},y_{2})$, then

$$y_{2}=mx_{2}+b.\qquad (4)$$

The difference $(4)-(2)$ gives

$$y_{2}-y_{1}=m(x_{2}-x_{1}).\qquad (5)$$

Hence $(1)$ becomes

$$y=\frac{y_{2}-y_{1}}{x_{2}-x_{1}}x+y_{1}-\frac{y_{2}-y_{1}}{x_{2}-x_{1}}%
x_{1}.\qquad (6)$$

For $P_{1}(5,10),P_{2}(50,100)$, the equation $(5)$ is

$$y=\frac{100-10}{50-5}x+10-\frac{100-10}{50-5}5,\qquad (7)$$

which is equivalent to

$$y=2x.\qquad (8)$$

For $y=23$, you have

$$23=2x.\qquad (9)$$

Thus

$$x=\frac{23}{2}.\qquad (10)$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use the two point form of [the equation for a line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_a_line).  For your example, it is $\frac{y-10}{x-5}=\frac{100-10}{50-5}$  Your line parallel to the $x$ axis is $y=23$.  So plug that into the first equation and solve for $x$.